# Best practice how to escape multi-select picklist field of object in dynamic SOQL request

Tags: apex, multi-select

I am trying to write dynamic SOQL queries, but I don't know the exactly correct way how to escape the multiselect picklist with multiple categories included the way it is working and not vulnerable to soql injection.

[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm) is the querying of multiselect picklist described without the escaping.

How can I pass variables with some categories etc to customize the query dynamically to select one or other (separated by comma) in one query?

This always return nothing. But separating with ';' works, because there are some values which consists both categories... How it is supposed work?

```
String category = 'ProductCat1,ProductCat2';
String soql = 'select Id, Category from Case where Category__c includes (:category) ';
Database.query(soql); // doesn't return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I'm not 100% sure this will work and don't have a fast way to test but based on the documentation you linked I would expect something like this to work:</s>

```
String category = 'ProductCat1,ProductCat2';
List<String> categories = category.split(',');
String soql = 'select Id, Category from Case where Category__c includes :categories'
Database.query(soql);
```

Give it a shot and it it doesn't work I'll delete this answer.

Update:

I was able to test original answer and it did not work.

Unfortunately I think this is the only way:

```
String category = 'Cat1,Cat2';
List<String> categories = category.split(',');
String soql = 'SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Category__c Includes(';

for (String s : categories) {
    soql += '\'' + EncodingUtils.escapeSingleQuotes(s) + '\',';
}

soql = soql.left(soql.length() -1); // strip off extra comma

soql += ')';

system.debug(soql);
```

### Ultimately:

Per the coumentation using ';' within a single string is treated as an `AND` operation. Ex. `includes ('abc;def')` for an `OR` operation you need to separate them into two strings Ex. `includes 'abc','def')`

Comment: This has always worked for me. One other recommendation would be to use bracket [] query syntax instead of Database.query. This will catch any syntax errors at compile-time, and the :categories syntax has better support, e.g. for nested objects (:myVar.categories) etc.

Comment: @NathanaelSchmolze I tested and it did not work for me. First error was "missing left parentesis" and second error was "invalid bind type List<String>". The updated code does work however.

Comment: @gNerb, Hmm, so the only option is to be escaping single quotes. I don't get, why just putting `:category` doesn't work. You get the variable from the frontend, so Salesforce could have expected, that we want to filter by that variable. Now I tried putting the string variable with categories into bracket query, and it doesn't work either! But if I put the same string directly between ( ) of include, escaped \' manually, it WORKS! So really, the only way, how to make a request is the way you described. Through Database.query() but with string you manually have to put into variable. Thank you.